# Launching of GC when Selenium basic program is run

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am running the following code in Eclipse but my Google Chrome is not launching.

The configurations are:

> - Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
> - Version: 2019-12 (4.14.0)
> - Have taken latest versions for GC driver.

The same code and config is working for another laptop but not on mine. Have re-installed the application several time.
All the libraries available on internet have also been imported.

```
package automationFramework;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;

public class FirstTestCase {

    public static WebDriver driver;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.driver", "C:\\Users\\WC-Parul\\Downloads\\geckodriver-v0.26.0-win64.zip");
        FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
        // Launch the Online Store Website
        // driver.get("http://www.shop.demoqa.com");
        // Print a Log In message to the screen
        System.out.println("Successfully opened the website www.Store.Demoqa.com");
        // Close the driver
        // driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you say Chrome? you are not use

```
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

you should

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

and you should download chromedriver.exe

Hope it helps you

If not, please take a screenshot "Java Build Path"

Answer (score 0):

Extract `C:\\Users\\WC-Parul\\Downloads\\geckodriver-v0.26.0-win64.zip` and provide `geckodriver.exe` path

Something like

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.driver", "C:\\Users\\WC-Parul\\Downloads\\geckodriver.exe");
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
```

Make sure your downloaded correct version of `geckodriver`

If you want to run the code on Chrome browser then download compatible `chromedriver.exe` from [here](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) as per your chrome browser version and use below code:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "drive_path\chromedriver.exe");
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
```